# Getting prompted for network credential when accessing guest VM

Tags: networking, windows-10, hyper-v, credentials

Since Hyper-V is considered a Type I hypervisor, you cannot access it directly from Windows (You cannot copy and paste from Windows to the guest OS).

In order to get around this limitation, I added a virtual internal switch and created a network.

My Host OS is Windows 10 and the guests are Windows XP and 7.

The problem facing me is that Windows 10 is asking for network credentials to connect to Windows 7 while I can browse the host (Windows 10) from the guest.

What is happening?

Comment: Based on your mentioning creating a virtual network switch and getting prompted for network credentials, when you say *"You cannot copy and paste"* I think you mean to say *you cannot copy files directly between the VM and the Host*. If so, please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Did you *ever* enter credentials for the Windows XP machine, even once?   If so, this is probably just a matter of the XP machine remembering your credentials, while the Windows 7 machine does not.  (Is your problem that the Windows 7 machine isn’t *accepting* your credentials?   If so, please make that clear.)

Comment: I do not have any credentials for Windows XP,  the weird thing is that I can access the shared folders on Windows 10(the guest) from Windows 7 (the host).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution and it is a network security related issue in Windows 10 Fall's Creators Update.

https://support.microsoft.com/de-ch/help/4046019/guest-access-smb2-disabled-by-default-in-windows-10-server-2016

Run -> gpedit.msc ->Computer configuration -> administrative templates -> network ->Lanman Workstation and Enable insecure guest logons